# Arrays that comply with .implements

Tags: java, arrays, generics, interface

so I have this exercise to solve. I have to create 1st. an interface called *Printable* that has one `put()` method that will accept objects that implement Comparable. **DONE**

```
interface Printable{
   <T extends Comparable<T>> void put();
}
```

Next I have two classes called *Point* and *Time* which have to implement the Printable interface. **Done**
Next off I have to create a method called `print()` that accepts an array of objects that extend *Printable* and print the whole array, **DONE**

```
    private static <T extends Printable> void print(T[] inArray){
        for(T element: inArray){
           element.put();
        }
    }
```

So now to test the code I create 1st array of type *Point* and use the code `print(theArray)` and it works fine. 2nd thing is to create an array of *Time*, **DONE** works fine ass well. But THEN last question is to create a ***mixed*** array of *points* and *time*. And here is my issue, when I create an array like this:

```
Object[] mixed = {new Point(x,y), new Point(t,s), new Time(i,u)...};
```

After I use the code `print(mixed);` I get a compile error, I know why... because Object does not extend Printable! which I defined in the `print()` method.. So my question is, how to create an array that will work here with the `print()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
Printable[] mixed = {new Point(x,y), new Point(t,s), new Time(i,u)...};
```

work?

edit 1:

(hint, I think so)

edit 2:

(Questioner assures me it works)

edit 3:

(orders from Star Captain Rosco confirms it works)

edit 4:

(The Romulans confirm it works)

edit 5:

([polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) is why it works)

edit 6:

(The funny thing is how silly the code looks after [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) gets through with it.)